# Rewrite to URL outside of Wordpress base

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

My wordpress blog is installed at `domain.com/blog` and I have a page with subpages whose structure look like `domain.com/blog/page` and `domain.com/blog/page/subpage`.

I want my visitors to be able to go to `domain.com/subpage` and see the content of `domain.com/blog/page/subpage` without being redirected to that URL externally, avoiding wordpress permalink rewrites.

I tried using `RewriteRule ^subpage$ /page/subpage [L]` and the content is being served, but the url looks like `domain.com/blog/page/subpage` (I'd guess Wordpress permalinks are getting to it.)

.htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

// tried inserting my code here.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

EDIT:

These logs show the activity on page visit -

```
ip - - [19/Jun/2012:14:03:53 -0400] "GET /subpage/ HTTP/1.1" 301 - "http://domain.com/referrer/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1"
ip - - [19/Jun/2012:14:03:53 -0400] "GET /blog/page/subpage/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20022 "http://domain.com/referrer/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1"
```

Also, here is my root .htaccess -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^subpage/?$ /blog/page/subpage/ [QSA,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
```

Comment: Try inserting your code *before* the `RewriteBase /blog/`

Comment: same issue - content loads, but url is still `/blog/page/subpage/`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you change your rule's regexp to: `^subpage/$`?

Comment: same result as mentioned

Answer (score 3):

Adding some rules in your htaccess, while using Wordpress, is always tricky. Instead, you should use its rewrite API.

**First**, put this code at then end of `/wp-content/themes/CURRENT_THEME_ACTIVATED/functions.php`:

```
function my_custom_page_rewrite_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^subpage/?', 'index.php?pagename=page/subpage', 'top');
}
add_filter('init', 'my_custom_page_rewrite_rule');
```

*Remark*: you need to specify the page levels in `pagename` parameter, otherwise the url will change.

**Then**, you need to tell Wordpress it has to take your new rule into consideration. For this, go to your admin panel: `Settings` > `Permalinks` > click on `Save` button. Now, you should be able to go to `domain.com/blog/subpage` and see the content of `domain.com/blog/page/subpage` (the url does not change anymore).

**Finally**, if you want to make `domain.com/subpage` reachable, you need to add a htaccess in root folder and put this code into it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ blog/$1 [L]
```

And... that's it. You can go to `domain.com/subpage` and now you'll get what you want.